# Makefile - Unix for C program

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to make a makefile on linux. When i run "make" on my makefile it only says " 'mkFile' is up to date", where mkFile is the name of my makefile. I dont have any .o files or a compiled program prior to running the make command. I only have C files in the directory, so i dont know why it wont generate the executable and .o files. I have 5 files: Main.c, convertSentence.c, convertAll.c, convertSentence.h, and convertAll.h

Main.c includes convertAll.h, and convertAll.c includes convertAll.h.

Here is my code:

```
main: Main.o convertSentence.o convertAll.o

gcc -o program Main.o convertSentence.o convertAll.o

Main.o: Main.c convertAll.h

gcc -c Main.c

convertAll.o: convertAll.c convertSentence.h

gcc -c convertAll.c

convertSentence.o: convertSentence.c

gcc -c convertSentence.c

clean:

rm *.o
```

Comment: indentation is broken in your makefile. each command must start by a TAB.

Comment: what command are you using to invoke make?

Answer (score 2):

> When i run "make" on my makefile it only says " 'mkFile' is up to date", where mkFile is the name of my makefile.

That indicates to me that you are using the following command line:

```
make mkFile
```

When you use that, it thinks it needs to build the target named `mkFile`.

You need to use:

```
make -f mkFile
```

When you use that, it indicates to `make` that the targets and dependencies for `make` are defined in the file named `mkFile`.

---

Another option is to rename `mkFile` to `makefile` or `Makefile` and then just use

```
make
```

Comment: Or just rename `mkFile` to just `Makefile` and then make will pick it up automatically without you having to specify the Makefile to use.`

Comment: That was my problem. Thanks! really simple issue i was having. Didnt use -f!

Comment: The other issue you had was you fibbed to us when you posted your question: you said you ran `make` but that's not what you ran at all.  Luckily for you R Sahu was able to guess what the real problem was.  So, lesson: always show the exact command you entered and the exact error output you got, preferably cut-and-pasted into the question.  Cheers!

Comment: And don't forget to read the `man pages`, e.g. `man 1 make : -f file Use file as a makefile.`